# take values from table cells and turn into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

using jquery I need to retrieve an array from table cells, format the data and pass it into a js function.

the code i am using is this:

```
 var l1 = new Array();
   $('table#datatable tbody td:first-child').each(function() {
   l1.push($(this).text());
   });
```

this is the table fragment

```
  <tr>
               <th scope="row">Age: 0-4</th>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>9.7</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th scope="row">5-17</th>
               <td>23.6</td>
               <td>18.0</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th scope="row">Total 0-17</th>
               <td>20.6</td>
               <td>16.1</td>
           </tr>
```

the table's id is "datatable". i want to return an array of the contents of each first td and then format it like this:
0,23.6,20.6

i am very new to using arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var l1 = $('#datatable td:nth-child(2)').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
//l1 = [0, 23.6, 20.6]
```

[See here for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jBQ52/)

This uses [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array from the elements.  Your main problem is that `:first-child` needs to be the first child **of the parent**, it doesn't mean the "first child of this type", so only a `<th>` would be `:first-child` in your code.  Instead you need the 2nd child, or `:nth-child(2)` to get the first `<td>` element.

Comment: DOH, i didnt realize that the TH counted as part of the set. this worked beautifully thanks. i am trying to create a plugin for jqPlot that converts tables to charts.

Comment: @liz - Ah I thought I recognized that markup, glad this worked you you. +1 on the question, asked exactly as it should be: including what you tried and the expected result, the markup/code is a huge plus and make the question much easier to answer, kudos.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var values = [];
$('#datatable tbody tr').each(function () {
    values.push($('td:first', this).text());
});
console.log(values);
```

Explanation:

- Line 1: create the `values` variable and set it to an empty array.
- Line 2: loop over every `tr` in `#datatable`.
- Line 3: add the text of the first `td` in the `tr` to the `values` array.
- `values` is now populated with the values.

Comment: This will add the text for all the `td` elements, not just the first one.

Comment: No, it won't - `.text()` will grab the first element automatically.

Comment: That is *not* correct, your result is: `["09.7", "23.618.0", "20.616.1"]`...see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/EUUjP/  Read the description for `.text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text/ "Get the **combined text** contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants."

Answer (score 1):

`td:first-child` won't match anything because none of the `<td>` elements are the first children (they are preceded by `<th>`). Instead, use `td:nth-child(2)`.